# I want to add one key and value pair in existing json file

Tags: java, json

I want to add the key value pair like

```
"Signature":64237402i242840805749670 in the existing json field properties

{
"headers":{
    "JMSCorrelationID":"The JMS correlation ID",
    "JMSDeliveryMode":"The JMS delivery mode",

},
"properties":{
    "asu_timestamp":"12345678",
    "asu_type":"Ack",
}
```

Please tell me how can I add it into Properties by using java.

Comment: Is your new key-value coming from any source and you wanted to add it in your existing JSON? one more, you want to add in particular tab(like headers, properties) or anywhere?

Comment: I am generating key-Value by using java code and I want to add it to existing JSON in properties tab

Comment: Okay, give me some time, I will give you the solution

Comment: okay no issues.

Comment: Is your JSON file located it drive?

Comment: I have saved my JSON file on desktop and retrieving from their

Comment: Ok then see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.sujit;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode;

public class JSONTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ObjectNode nodes = mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\test.json"),ObjectNode.class);
            nodes.with("properties").put("Signature", "64237402i242840805749670 ");
            mapper.writer().writeValue(new File("D:\\test.json"), nodes); // Overwritting the file with new updated JSON data
        }
}
```

Add the jar **jackson-all-1.9.0** jar file into your class build path, (link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonall190jar.htm)

Otherwise if you are using maven, add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah the code is working.Great help from you.Thank you so much.